# Android duplicate Contacts shown in Listview

Tags: android, listview, contacts

In my android application I am opening my contacts list and showing it in a listview.. but when I test the app in mobile... some contacts are repeated 5-6 times. But in Emulator it is working fine. I am giving my code below.. If any eroor please help me..

```
Cursor c = this.managedQuery(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null,
        Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", // condition
        new String[] {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
        }, // value
        null);

ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

while (c.moveToNext())
{
    int type = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
    if (type == Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
    {
        Contact con = new Contact(c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)), c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER)));
        contacts.add(con);
    }
}

listView.setAdapter(new ContactsAdapter(this, contacts));
```

Comment: First of all check your arraylist contacts contains duplicate element or not

Comment: check contact list in your device. It might have multiple contacts, because when you sink more than one google account, it will create duplicate records also.

Comment: From my experience these type of problem is related to the listadapter where something is wrong with the list-item-recycling.

Comment: why don't you use `SimplecursorAdapter`, why do you make your life harder?

Comment: Can u give me a sample... of simplecursor adapter

Comment: paste your adapter here.

Comment: see https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure all your c(s) are different from each other?
I mean, the data you're getting in the Cursor are correct when you launch the app in the smartphone? There are no duplicates?

Comment: @ stefano... i didnt understand

Comment: @Jocheved you can do a quick test: duplicated contacts are always the same or they change from time to time? In the first case I suggest you to check and filter the data collected with the Cursor, in the second case you're having troubles with the UI/ListView

Comment: @ Stefano.. it is changing... once it is shown one contact at starting.. then that contact will be third or fourth next time... but that contact will get rerepaeted...

Comment: @Jocheved i don't care about the ordering of contacts.. let's say you have 3 contacts, A B and C, but you always collect **A once, B once and C 3 times**. Is that your case? Or you have a changing situation from time to time, so, for example, the first time you have **A once, B once, C 3 times** --- **A 3 times, B once, C 4 times**

Comment: @Jocheved how many contacts do you expect to have in your smartphone (let's say 100 unique contacts)? well, check if you cycle for that 100 contacts (you get 100 rows from the Cursor) or if you are getting 400 `c`(s) (you have 400 rows from the Cursor --> you have duplicates to filter in the Cursor!)

Comment: I checked it now...I have total 9 contacts say A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I Suppose it is in this order A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H.A,I,B,B,D,C,... then it is going in the same repeating order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89159/discussion-between-stefano-and-jocheved).